How to migrate from FCM Legacy API to Http V1 in terms of code in java for android?
My app uses FCM legacy API to send notifications. But those APIs were deprecated on June 20, 2023, and will be removed in June 2024. In FCM Legacy Api I have used the following code to send notifications
private void sendPushNotification(String notificationTitle, String hisFcmToken, String notificationBody, String myUserID, String notificationPhotoUrl, String hisUserID) {        
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

        JSONObject notificationObj = new JSONObject();
        notificationObj.put("title", notificationTitle);
        notificationObj.put("body", notificationBody);
        notificationObj.put("image", notificationPhotoUrl);
        notificationObj.put("priority", "high");

        JSONObject dataObj = new JSONObject();
        dataObj.put("isNewUncheckedLikeNotification", "true");
        dataObj.put("likerUserID", myUserID);

        jsonObject.put("notification", notificationObj);
        jsonObject.put("data", dataObj);
        jsonObject.put("to", hisFcmToken);

        callApi(jsonObject, hisUserID);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("sendLikePushNotification", "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

private void callApi(JSONObject jsonObject, String hisUserID) {
    MediaType JSON = MediaType.get("application/json; charset=utf-8");
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    String url = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";
    RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(jsonObject.toString(), JSON);
    Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url).post(body).header("Authorization", "Bearer Authorization_key").build();
    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Call call, @NonNull IOException e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NonNull Call call, @NonNull Response response) throws IOException {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                Log.d("PushNotification", "Notification successfully sent.");
            } else {
                Log.d("PushNotification", "Failed to send notification: " + response.code() + " " + response.message());
            }
        }
    });
}

I have read this documentation but unable to understand clearly. I need an example code snippet or tutorial where the send notification is implemented completely. Thanks anyways.

There are three areas that you have to update in order to align with the FCM upgrade. Here is the overview. Each of them is attached with a reference link for documentation.
**** Implementation attached at the end of the answer.!!

Note: The bellow code examples have example values. So, replace them
with real values according to the notification project.

01. Update the API URL: reference
API Url before:
POST https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send

API Url After:
POST https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/myproject-b5ae1/messages:send

02. Implement Auth2.0 for Authorisation: reference
Authorization before:
Authorization: key=AIzaSyZ-1u...0GBYzPu7Udno5aA

Authorization after:
Authorization: Bearer ya29.ElqKBGN2Ri_Uz...HnS_uNreA

03. Restructure the payload: reference
Payload before:
  { "notification": {
      "body": "This is an FCM notification message!",
      "time": "FCM Message"
    },
    "to" : "bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1..."
  }

Payload After:
{
   "message":{
      "token":"bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
      "notification":{
        "body":"This is an FCM notification message!",
        "title":"FCM Message"
      }
   }
}

Implementation:
01. GoogleCredentials Configuration class
@Configuration
@PropertySource({"classpath:application.yml"})
public class GoogleCredentialsConfig {

    @Value("${fcm_private_key_file_path}")
    String googleServiceAccountPrivateKeyFilePath;//JSON file

    @Bean
    public GoogleCredentials getGoogleCredentials() {
        try {
            FileInputStream serviceAccount = new FileInputStream(googleServiceAccountPrivateKeyFilePath);
            GoogleCredentials googleCredentials = GoogleCredentials
                    .fromStream(serviceAccount)
                    .createScoped(List.of(
                            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging"
                    ));
            return googleCredentials;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("ERROR OCCURRED WHILE GENERATING FCM ACCESS TOKEN: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

02. Create a new token if expired
public String getServiceAccountAccessToken() throws IOException {
    GoogleCredentials googleCredentials = googleCredentialsConfig.getGoogleCredentials();
    googleCredentials.refreshIfExpired();
    String accessToken = googleCredentials.getAccessToken().getTokenValue();
    return accessToken;
}

03. Send POST request to FCM:
    URL url = new URL(fcmProjectEndpoint);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + getServiceAccountAccessToken());
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; utf-8");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
    conn.setDoOutput(true);

    // Send FCM message content.
    OutputStream outputStream = conn.getOutputStream();
    outputStream.write(pushMessage.getBytes());
    outputStream.flush();
    outputStream.close();
    if (conn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
        success = true;//
    }

    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()))) {
        StringBuilder responseBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            responseBuilder.append(line);
        }
        response = responseBuilder.toString();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOG.error("Error reading FCM response: " + e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        if (conn != null) {
            conn.disconnect();
        }
    }

LOG.info("Response: " + response);


The credentials part in the middle was the key for me getting this working.  We had to export our credentials as JSON, and use them to get the token as shown.  Thanks.
